# Find data-usage for each wifi user

Tags: wireless-networking

We have broadband internet connection at our apartment with WiFi. We are three flatmates and some of them do heavy downloading, while others just browse the web. We would like to divide our internet bill in the ratios of our data consumption. Is there a way to know the data-usage by each user?

Comment: Why would you want to divide the bill? Do you pay more for a higher volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often you can monitor your bandwidth usage on a per-device bases on the router itself. Open up the admin console on your router to see if you have that option, some routers provide that functionality, some don't.

If your router doesn't support that functionality, that's still not a problem, you can install a custom firmware on your router such as [DD-WRT](https://www.dd-wrt.com) or [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato). Both of those firmwares include the functionality to monitor bandwidth, or at least have existing plugins. For example, it looks like [this forum post](https://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=81432) does exactly what you're looking for using DD-WRT. [And here is a guide](http://www.nextgendigitalhome.com/2127/home-network/scalable-gateway/using-the-tomato-firmware-to-monitor-bandwidth-by-ip-address/) for the same thing on Tomato.

The benefit of doing this on your router is that there is no need for an additional server software or hardware, and no installation that needs to be done on the client computers.

Answer (score 0):

**PRTG Network Monitor - intuitive network monitoring software** is your way to go.
This probably requires something like a Server (however it can work on a Simple PC/Laptop)

This is a network monitor tool allowing you to monitor every aspect of your network. In order this to work your flatmates should agree installing Probe Applications on their computers. For 10 Sensors there's a freeware version.

http://www.paessler.com/prtg